# Python: dynamic class generation: overwrite members

Tags: python, inheritance, name-mangling, dynamic-class-creation

I have a python class hierarchy, that I want to extend at runtime. Furthermore every class in this hierarchy has a static attribute 'dict', that I want to overwrite in every subclass. Simplyfied it looks like this:

#### 'dict' is a protected (public but with leading underscore) member

```
class A(object):
    _dict = {}

    @classmethod
    def getdict(cls):
        return cls._dict

    @classmethod
    def setval(cls, name, val):
        cls._dict[name] = val

    @classmethod
    def addchild(cls, name):
        return type(name, (cls, ), { '_dict' : {} })

B = A.addchild('B')
A.setval(1, 5)

print A.getdict()
# prints: {1: 5}
# like expected

print B.getdict()
# prints: {}
# like expected
```

This works just like expected. The question now is: why doesnt it work anymore if I declare the attribute private:

#### Now the same thing with 'dict' beeing a private member

```
class C(object):
    __dict = {}

    @classmethod
    def getdict(cls):
        return cls.__dict

    @classmethod
    def setval(cls, name, val):
        cls.__dict[name] = val

    @classmethod
    def addchild(cls, name):
        return type(name, (cls, ), { '__dict' : {} })

D = C.addchild('D')
C.setval(1, 5)

print C.getdict()
# prints: {1: 5}
# like expected

print D.getdict()
# prints: {1: 5}
# why!?
```

Suddenly `D`, the subclass of `C`, has the same values in 'dict' as its superclass!?

Could anyone be so kind and explain to me, what the reason for this is? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phild, as you know, when you prefix an attribute name with double-underscore `__`, the python interpreter automagically changes (mangles) attribute name from `__attribute` to `_CLS__attribute`, where CLS is the class name.

However, when you say

`return type(name, (cls, ), { '__dict' : {} })`

the keys in the dictionary `{ '__dict' : {} }` do not get mangled. `__dict` remains the same.

Thus D ends up with both `D._C__dict` and `D.__dict`:

```
(Pdb) dir(D)
['_C__dict', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'addchild', 'getdict', 'setval']
```

`D._C__dict` refers to C's class attribute. So when you run

`C.setval(1, 5)`

you are changing `D._C__dict` as well as `C._C__dict`. They are one and the same.

Comment: Thanks! A very clear explanation to the problem I had. Now this all makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [chapter in documentation about "private" attributes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). And I commented you class definition to make it more clear:

```
class C(object):
    __dict = {} # This creates C.__dict__['_C__dict']

    @classmethod
    def getdict(cls):
        return cls.__dict # Uses cls.__dict__['_C__dict'] 

    @classmethod
    def setval(cls, name, val):
        cls.__dict[name] = val # Uses cls.__dict__['_C__dict'] 

    @classmethod
    def addchild(cls, name):
        return type(name, (cls, ), { '__dict' : {} }) # Creates child.__dict__['__dict']
```

I.e. all childs have their own `__dict` attribute, but only one from base class is used.

Comment: thanks, that made it clearer to me. Still wondering why this behaves differently if 'dict' is public. The 'D.getdict()' method call would in this case use the _D_dict attribute. Isnt this a bit inconsistent of python?

Comment: The name mangling is applied to names starting with two underscores only.

Comment: Yeah, it's not what you'd call a pretty feature. The name mangling happens at compile time, and only affects identifiers, not strings.

Comment: Aaaah ok! Thanks very much Denis! That was the thing I wasnt thinking about.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff compile time?

Comment: Yes—at the time Python checks the code for SyntaxErrors, before it runs any of the code. All Python code is compiled to bytecode before it starts running.

Answer (score 1):

The Java or C++ concepts of "protected" and "private" do not apply.  The naming convention Python does a little, but not what you're imagining.

The `__name` does some name mangling, making it hard to access because the name is obscured.

Your `_dict` and `__dict` are simply class-level attributes that are simply shared by all instances of the classes.

Comment: Yes, it is clear to me that python only does name mangling, and that i could also access private attributes from outside the class, if I wanted to. But: why do they behave differently then, if i declare the attribute private or protected/public?